# Installing SVN on XAMPP - Invalid command 'DAV'

Tags: svn, xampp

I am trying to install subversion on my XAMPP following this guide:
http://noobcode.blogspot.nl/2010/03/what-is-subversion-as-quoted-by.html

```
**Installed versions**
Subversion: 1.8.14
Latest XAMPP install: Apache 2.4.16
```

I get stuck at point 10: starting Apache after adding the following to apache httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath "g:/svn"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "All my repositories"
   AuthUserFile "g:/svn/passwords"
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

After restarting Apache via command line I get the following error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 564 of G:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'DAV', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the sentence I already found the answer here:
http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/general-setup-and-troubleshooting/5724-dav-svn

> It turns out the line
>
> LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
>
> was still commented. My instructions didn't say anything about that
>   line (I guess the thought it would be uncommented by default). I
>   uncommented it and the service started up.
>
> Thanks for the assist.

Thank you for reading :)